# cannot connect ms sql to php7 on windows 10

Tags: php

i have windows 10 64 bit  and i installed php7 and apache 2.4 but i cannot  connect to  ms sql 2008 R2  i downloaded the drivers and moved them to the  ext folder of the php and modify the php.ini but cannot see them in the phpinfo() page 
[php/ext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58L2X.png)

[php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zid4Q.png)

the first image see the two files i downloaded 
the second image show i edited the php.ini 
but i still cannot connect

[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOvof.png)

the third one show that no pdo drivers and no 
sqlsrv 
any solution guys ???

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it is self-contained? The way it is will make it useless if your linked information goes away. Thanks.

Comment: If it was me I would do a migration to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this, I overlooked that you did have the drivers in your op

You need to install the Microsoft SQL server drivers. Your op didn't mention that these were installed.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

[Microsoft SQL server php drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)